# I need to be able to download or the monthly invoice from the resellers billing section in the Google resellers console

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I have had a look at the G Suite Reseller API and could not find how to download the monthly billing information, can anyone please help me that has been able to get this right. We have multiple reseller consoles and we want to automate the process.